# I can't start api explorer on localhost error: INCLUDE_DOT_API_FILES

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I run the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer
```

Result in an Error 500:

I don't know what i did wrong...
Somebody has a point?

(Admin Console etc. works...)

[image]

```
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>services</param-name>
    <param-value>app.mds.ams.server.api.AppApi</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
```

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```